# Filter one column by not matching to another column

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

How can I create a dataframe containing the records of the `table1` table that **DO NOT match** the `istituto, service_rap, filiale_rap, codice_rap` fields with the table `table2`

I tried something like this (but this don't work):

```
val result: Dataset[Row] = table1.where($"istituto".notEqual(table2("istituto")))
val result: Dataset[Row] = table1.where($"istituto" =!= (table2("istituto")))
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) istituto#16 missing from istituto#42,servizio_rap#43,filiale_rap#44,codice_rap#45,ndg#46 in operator !Filter NOT (istituto#42 = istituto#16). Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: istituto. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;
!Filter NOT (istituto#42 = istituto#16)
```

table1:

```
  private val table1: DataFrame = Seq(
    ("03104", "001", "00002", "123456", "ndg1"),
    ("03104", "001", "00002", "123455", "ndg2")
  ).toDF("istituto", "servizio_rap", "filiale_rap", "codice_rap", "ndg")
```

table2:

```
  private val secondInput: DataFrame = Seq(
    ("03106", "001", "00002", "123456", "ndg1"))
    .toDF("istituto", "servizio_rap", "filiale_rap", "codice_rap", "ndg")
```

Expected result:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+----------+----+
|istituto|servizio_rap|filiale_rap|codice_rap|ndg |
+--------+------------+-----------+----------+----+
|03106   |002         |00003      |123465    |ndg1|
+--------+------------+-----------+----------+----+
```

Comment: Everything in table1 and table2 is a string

Comment: the `istituto` is the same for both lines in table1, is it a typo ?

Also, the result of `servizio_rap` and `filiale_rap` is different from the values that are in the tables

Comment: In table 1 istituto the same, it is not a typo. `servizio_rap` and `filiale_rap` are just a data examples to visualize my problem.

Comment: Resolved using 'leftanti' join

`val result: DataFrame = secondInput.join(input,Seq("servizio_rap","filiale_rap","codice_rap","istituto"),"leftanti")`

Comment: Nice ! Could you write it as an answer so that people with the same problem could find the solution as well ? most don't read comment section

Comment: @IsmailH I can't answer question. could you please post this answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment made by [Miko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12402121).

Resolved using `leftanti` join

```
val result: DataFrame = secondInput.join(input,Seq("servizio_rap","filiale_rap","codice_rap","istituto"),"leftanti")
```